# How, using TortoiseSVN, to include some of a file's changed lines but not others in a commit?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I know this is possible with git (by selecting which changed lines in which changed files you want to bundle together in a single commit before then executing the commit).

Is this also in svn (and Tortoise SVN)?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with TortoiseSVN, but:

- only partially the same way, as in Git
- only with TortoiseSVN 1.8 - read ["Commit only parts of a file"](http://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.8_releasenotes.html#commitparts) in Release Notes

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible with SVN.

Create a backup copy of your file. Then edit the file and make it contain what you want to commit, then commit, then restore the backup copy.

That said, I would not call that a good practice, even with git. You'd better use branches to make unrelated changes to the same file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do that by hand. Edit your file to select only the change you want (after making a backup) and commit.